# Using OAuth securely in JavaScript to save bandwidth

Tags: oauth

I want the users of my website to use Dropbox to store their files. I will be using OAuth 1.0 for this purpose. I can't use OAuth 2.0 as Dropbox only supports OAuth 1.0.

If I completely implement the authorization and file retrieval/storage at the server-side it will cost me a lot of bandwidth for the file storage/retrieval. I thought of completely shifting this to JavaScript for saving the bandwidth. However, in that case the consumer secret will be exposed to the world causing security issues.

To prevent the consumer secret exposure I have thought of performing the request_token, authorize and access_token phases at the server-side. Then pass the necessary parameters to JavaScript which will then handle storage and retrieval of files.

Is this a good idea? Or can you see any problems in it?

Comment: Note: I do not want to use the YQL solution mentioned at http://derek.io/blog/2010/how-to-secure-oauth-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes perfect sense.

As long as you make absolutely sure that none of your keys/secrets appear anywhere in your JavaScript code, and make absolutely sure to only persist keys/secrets for the duration of the session you should be safe.

**EDIT**: You can of course persist the access token to Dropbox server side beyond the scope of the session. That way you can reuse the same access token across several sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, the only thing is if the endpoint, in your case Dropbox, supports CORS, aka returns ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN permitting the browser to post to it. Otherwise you could post via a FORM but i dont think you'll be able to read the response.

FYI i've wrapped this into a clientside library, take a look at http://adodson.com/hello.js/ and serverside OAuth1 shim https://npmjs.org/package/oauth-shim